# Rename file with InkFilePicker

Tags: filepicker.io

I'm evaluating the InkFilePicker service. How do I make sure that uploading a new file to my S3 bucket won't overwrite an existing file with an identical name already in that bucket?

I'm currently using another third party upload solution that allows me to rename a file with a GUID as its file name to prevent such accidental overwrite situations.

How do rename files using InkFilePicker? Or what is the right approach with InkFilePicker to prevent unintended overwrites?

Thanks,
Sam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like InkFilePicker prepends a unique key to file name during upload.

myfile.pdf becomes something like DNjimbeSQWVrcd0Uv8lJ_myfile.pdf when it's saved on Amazon S3 so it inherently prevents overwrites.